# Is it possible to make the user section of my website a SPA and the admin section MPA in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

So I'm building a website in laravel and I would like to make my user section of the website use vue-router making it a SPA. For the admin section I would like it to be a MPA where each route takes you to a new page.
I think I have an idea on how to go about it. What I plan on doing is having all my admin related routes come before the route that directs any  request to the SPA controller. Is that a good way to do it?.

Comment: I did the opposite (admin as SPA and main site as MPA). I made my admin using Vue CLI and getting data using an API i creayed on the Laravel side. My main site will still be using Vue but as an MPA.

Comment: Interesting,  so it is possible then. Can I achieve it without making my user section completely separated from laravel(vue cli)

Comment: Hmmmmm, maybe you could try, like create an SPA and define routes only used by your SPA (in api.php maybe). You'd probably also need 2 Vue instances, 1 for your admin with ```el: '#admin-app'``` and the other for your main site ```el: '#app'```. To one of these instance you could add vue-router to it. I'm just saying, never tried it, but that's what I would try. Maybe someone has a better way than me to do this.

Comment: Thanks alot , I'll give it a try.

Comment: Nice, I'd like to know if it worked when you'll be done with this :)

Comment: It's working good so far .thanks alot.

Comment: Woow awesome! I'll surely give it a try, I'm actually doing a project where I need to do this :)